# add axis titles to 3d surface plot cufflinks & plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Would anyone be able to give me a tip on how to add x,y,z axis titles to the 3 surface plot created with plotly & cufflinks?

Im using Jupyter notebooks Anaconda 3.7

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
# Using plotly + cufflinks in offline mode
import cufflinks
cufflinks.go_offline(connected=True)
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# creating dataframe with three axes 
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                    'y':[10, 20, 30, 20, 10], 
                    'z':[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}) 

# colorscale:red(rd), yellow(yl), blue(bu) 
df.iplot(kind ='surface', colorscale ='rdylbu')
```

Any tips help thanks.

Comment: Does [this documentation](https://plot.ly/python/figure-labels/) give you the answer you need?

Comment: One thing that is confusing to me is If this needs to be defined thru cufflinks or a plotly layout which seems to be in the link you provided.. I think the 'df.iplot()' is plotly but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: have you tried that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import pandas as pd

# creating dataframe with three axes 
data = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                    'y':[10, 20, 30, 20, 10], 
                    'z':[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}) 

data = [
    go.Surface(
        z = data.as_matrix()
    )
]
layout = go.Layout(
    title='My Surface',
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=600,
    margin=dict(
        l=65,
        r=50,
        b=65,
        t=90
    ),
    scene = {"xaxis":{"title":"my x axis name"},
             "yaxis":{"title":"my pretty y axis name"},
             "zaxis":{"title":"Z AXIS"}}
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: In IPython the graphs renders in a different browser tab, sort of cool. I never seen that feature before... How/where in the code is the configuration to bring up the graph in `temp-plot.html`? Thanks for the help

Comment: As soon as you run the script the graph will be brought automatically in front.